# $\mathbb Z[x_n]$ is always a UFD?

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, factorial, minimal-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Let $n$ be a positive integer and consider $f(x,n) = \frac{x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}$ where $x^{(m)}$ is the rising factorial:
$$\begin{align*}
x^{(1)} &= x\\
x^{(2)} &= x(x+1)\\
x^{(3)} &= x(x+1)(x+2)\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$
Now define $x_n$ by
$$f(x_n,n) = -1$$
(what is its minimum polynomial)

We now can make a ring by extending the integers: $\mathbb Z[x_n]$.

For instance, $f(x_1,1) = -1$. This means solving
$$-1 = x(x+1)/2$$
we get
$$x = (-1 + \sqrt -7)/2$$
or
$$  x = (-1 - \sqrt -7)/2$$

But we just write $x_1$  for both solutions.

Then our ring is $\mathbb Z[x_1]$ or simply said the ring
$a + b x_1$ for integers $a,b$.

I believe $\mathbb Z[x_1]$ is a UFD (unique factoring domain).

In fact I conjecture:

> For all $n>0$, $\mathbb Z[x_n]$ is a UFD.

Any (dis)proofs or counterexamples ?

Comment: I think a fair addition would be to explain *why* it is you think they're UFDs, for example indicate if you have looked into it for at least the first few (or some of the first few) terms of the sequence, etc... Not necessarily paragraphs upon paragraphs, but just *something* that'd explain your intuition, if that makes sense?

Comment: @BrunoB in a sense these monic polynomials are the smallest possible with respect to their degree. Just like the triangular numbers are the strictly increasing and even accelerating polynomial of lowest degree that grow the slowest, yet they map integers to integers.
The slow rate of these monic polynomials with respect to their degree makes me believe their solutions ( the algebraic solutions when set equal to -1) are ' special fundamental numbers '. They are also complicated, they have no short closed form so things like factoring small integers more than one way unlikely for these numbers.

Comment: Your formatting is not good; you have too many blank lines before and after displayed equations, and too many displayed equations that should be in-line for readability. After ten years on the site, this should be competently formatted, and it is not.

Comment: This is an extremely roundabout way of saying that $x_n$ is a zero of $x^{(2n)}+(2n)!$. It is worth noting that this is of the form $f(x^2+(2n-1)x)$ for some polynomial of degree $n$, ending in 
$$f(t)=t^n+\ldots+(2n-2)!t+(2n)!.$$
Do you have *any* thoughts on the matter? Or are you just stringing some nice-sounding jargon together?

Comment: @Servaes +1 
But I do not know what you mean by nice-sounding jargon ? Rising factorial ? Minimum polynomial ? In fact I barely see jargon at all.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Strange, it looked ok on my computer.  Thanks for editing.

Comment: @Servaes as for the roundabout, I wanted to show how it was constructed. See my comment answer to Bruno B, despite being informal and just some intuition.